# How to prove m%n is equivalent to m&(n-1) when n is 2^k?

Tags: java, dictionary, hash, hashmap, thread-local

Notice that '%' is a remainder operator and '&' is a bitwise AND operator, and k is an integer bigger than 0.

Example:

```
33%16=1 equivalent to 33&(16-1)=1
```

I found this equivalent in JDK1.8 ThreadLocalMap. I know it is correct but don't how to prove it is correct. I would be appreciated if you could give some help.

Comment: Mathematical prove?

Comment: Yes, or maybe programming related prove can help too.

Comment: It's a well-established mathematical identity. You don't need a proof, any more than you need a proof of 1+1=2.

Comment: @user207421 Cmon, it's not *that* simple. :D

Comment: This is more axiomatic.   `2^k` is always `1` followed by `k` 0's  so `n-1` is just a mask of `k` 1's. So `m&(n-1)` gives  you the low order `k` bits of `m`, just like `m%n`.

Comment: @akuzminykh Not what simple? I didn't say anything about it being simple. I said it was a well-established mathematical identity for which the OP doesn't actually need a proof.

Comment: @user207421 And the OP asks about the *how*. Where's the point in just *simply* saying *"You don't need a proof"*. You need it when you want to understand it, established or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`m % n` is the remainder of dividing m by n and is therefore a number between 0 and n-1,  or between 0 and 2^k - 1.

2^k in binary is one followed by k zeroes. 2^k -1 is k contiguous ones.

`m & n` is m & (2^k - 1) is a number in which, in binary, the 1 bits must occur in the rightmost k bits.  It is therefore in the range 0 to 2^k - 1.

QED.